# Does Fossil-Scm have the ability to add new ticket statuses?

Tags: fossil

Is it possible to add new status codes to Fossil SCM besides `Fixed`,`Tested`,`Closed` etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

The 'status' field of the ticket table is a text field, so basically, you can use any status you want.

You can change the list of statuses available in the ticket page's drop-down box:

- go to the `Admin` page
- click `tickets`
- click `Common`.

On that page, you can edit the list of `status_choices` (amongst others). The order you specify here is the order the statuses will be shown in the drop-down box. If you want to include a space inside a status, put it between "double quotes".

When you're done editing, don't forget to click the `Apply Changes` button.